# I want to create something like this but how can i add a check mark when the user clicks it. This is fixed.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

[image]

I am open to using bootstrap or font-awesome.
I just need to create an HTML and then I can add javascript later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented on pure css

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

The original post is on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Comment: Thanks I couldnot find it on w3c before. I can work with this